# How to solve the following nonhomogeneous second order ODE with these boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have formulated a problem in an internal flow between two plates and I ended up with the following ODE:

[image]

,and the boundary conditions are:

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousDE.aspx

Comment: @WaisKamal
Thanks, but I have problem in working with the given boundary conditions.